# Bibliography with author names as last, first

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to show in the bibliography, the authors last name first then the first name. How to do that?

Please refer to the attached code and bib file.

I have many references in bib file but for example I use only three.

Latex code

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,leqno]{book}
\input psfig.sty
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=-0.5in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.5in
%\topmargin=-1.5in
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Old day at school \cite{abram1972,austrian1982,babbage1832}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Bib file is

```
@book{abram1972,
author               = {Abramowitz, M. I. and Stegun, I. A.},
owner                = {ray},
publisher            = {Dover Publications},
title                = {Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas,Graphs, and Mathematical Tables},
year                 = {1972},
}

@book{austrian1982,
__markedentry        = {[rayn:1]},
author               = {Austrian, Geoffrey D},
owner                = {mine_design},
publisher            = {Columbia University Press},
title                = {Herman Hollerith: forgotten giant of information processing},
year                 = {1982},
 }

@book{babbage1832,
__markedentry        = {[rayn:1]},
author               = {Babbage, Charles},
owner                = {mine_design},
publisher            = {Taylor \& Francis},
title                = {On the economy of machinery and manufactures},
year                 = {1832},
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to be using `biblatex`, so I have re-tagged your question accordingly, so people don't get confused. BTW: Your MWE, while exhibiting your problem very clearly, could be made slightly more minimal by kicking out irrelevant packages (irrelevant to the question at hand, that is) like `epsfig`, `caption`, `\input psfig.sty` and your  margin settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `biblatex+biber` it's simple. The syntax for producing a bibliography is slightly different: you define the .bib files in the preamble with the `\addbibresource` command, load `biblatex, and simply write`\printbibliography where you want it to be. Note I changed the input encoding to `utf8` as `biber` understands it.

Also, `times` is obsolete, you should use `mathptmx` or even better, `newtx`. I don't see why you should load `psfig` and `epsfig`, since you load `graphicx.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,leqno]{book}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=-0.5in
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=9.5in
%\topmargin=-1.5in
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@book{abram1972,
author = {Abramowitz, M. I. and Stegun, I. A.},
owner = {ray},
publisher = {Dover Publications},
title = {Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas,Graphs, and Mathematical Tables},
year = {1972},
}

@book{austrian1982,
__markedentry = {[rayn:1]},
author = {Austrian, Geoffrey D},
owner = {mine_design},
publisher = {Columbia University Press},
title = {Herman Hollerith: forgotten giant of information processing},
year = {1982},
 }

@book{babbage1832,
__markedentry = {[rayn:1]},
author = {Babbage, Charles},
owner = {mine_design},
publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
title = {On the economy of machinery and manufactures},
year = {1832},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
 \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
Old day at school \cite{abram1972,austrian1982,babbage1832}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what would happen if I have long list of references in my bib file? Is there anyway to recall it from .bib file rather than write it on the main latex file, Also the code you given doesn't work

Comment: When I run your code. I can't see references in the pdf file. But I can see "Old day at school [abram1972, austrian1982, babbage1832]". No references at the end of pdf file.

Comment: Did you run the cycle `pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex`?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: which system/distribution/editor do you have?

Comment: I tried to compile the code in Texstudio 2.9.4 and WinEdt 9

Comment: Any update of this issue?

Comment: @Harry: I use WinEdt9.  To compile with `pdflatex`, you should have a compilation button in the tool bar. To launch biber you should have two buttons, next to each other: one for `bibtex` (with the letter `B`), one for `biber` (with `B+`). You just have to click on them successively (waiting for the action to be finished each time.